# Copy a Steam game to a USB flash drive

Tags: steam, retro-city-rampage

I have an 8GB USB drive which is completely empty and I would like to copy [Retro City Rampage: DX](https://steamdb.info/app/204630/) to it.

Is there a way I can copy to the USB so I can play it on another PC without Steam being required on the PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Schism's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/250344/6462) is correct, but you may be interested as to why.

The sticking point is licensing.

"Buying a game" does not mean just acquiring a copy of the game, buying a game means you have purchased a license to play the game, and you have been given a copy of the files that make up the game. These files include software to confirm you have a license.

When games came on easily replicated media (like floppy discs), this was done by proving you had the manual or a dongle or a cardboard wheel to prove you had something to prove the license, not just a copy of a game files.

As soon as the internet became popular, CD keys were used as one-time validation tokens to be sent to a server to prove you had a license as well as a copy of the game files.

Steam comes along, as well as a nifty store and library, steam has baked the licensing in to the games, so you barely have to think about it or worry about keys or [cardboard wheels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IiLOwxcuwM).

So, if you have purchased a game from steam, <s>you need steam to activate your license</s> you probably need steam to activate your license to play the game.

[@ardaozkal's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/250369/6462) has details of DRM-free games. (DRM stands Digitial Rights Management, which licensing falls under).

Answer (score 6):

No. You will need Steam installed on the other PC, and you'll need to be logged into an account that owns that game.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes for some games, and no for Retro City Rampage: DX.**

In order to play a game without steam/the platform you bought it on, it needs to be *DRM-free*. [Here is a list of the DRM-free games on Steam](http://steam.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_DRM-free_games). Unfortunately, Retro City Rampage: DX is not DRM-free.

As a sidenote, all games in [GOG (formerly Good Old Games)](http://gog.com) are DRM-free.

Comment: This doesn't mean much to the initial question, but I believe that it is more descriptive about why it isn't playable. Also, for more description about DRM, read @StuperUser's answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is doable. In my experienced I have purchased CSGO and installed it in my PC but later I got a new laptop so I decided to copy it and paste it in. I just copy the steamapps on my PC C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps and paste it on my laptop same directory. but you need to login the steam account that purchased that game before playing it.

Comment: The question states: "without Steam being required on the PC"